# Update parent value every time iframe reloads with iframe value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with an iFrame and want to update a value in the parent each time the iFrame loads from a form submit in the iFrame. This is the code in the parent :

```
<div id="updField" style="display: block; float: left; margin: 12px 0px 0px 20px; width: 300px; font-size: 14px; color: #CC0000;">
   Test Update Field
</div>
```

This is the jQuery in the iFrame:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#updField", window.parent.document).text("<?php echo $dupdate; ?>");
});
```

When first time the iFrame loads, parent div changes to show the value of `$dupdate`. If I submit a form which is in the iFrame which changes the `$dupdate` value, the parent div does not update. I want the parent div to update each time the iFrame loads. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To debug it step by step, try setting the text on Submit event of form.

Comment: Apart from actual question : Are you trying to run PHP on client side : `.text("<?php echo $dupdate; ?>");`. You need to send back the data and use that on the client side, you cannot write PHP in Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: No its a php page and there is no problem with the $dupdate variable the first time the page loads. It is on subsequent loading that the parent div doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Ok, here's the full, working code.  Sorry for the errors earlier. Same idea.  The parent keeps track of the child load events and then reaches in and gets the value you want from a div somewhere.

Two files: blah.html and childblah.html.

**Blah.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myFrame").on("load", function () {
    var infoContainer = $("#myFrame").contents().find("#someDiv");
    if (infoContainer!=null)
       $("#updField").text(infoContainer.text());
        });
        });

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="childblah.html" > </iframe>
    <div id="updField">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**childblah.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){document.location.href='childblah.html';},3000)">
    <div id="someDiv">
        xxxxxxx<div id='dv' />
        <script>var dt=new Date();document.getElementById('dv').innerHTML=dt;</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can just get the content from a specified location if it exists instead of having the child write the value.

Comment: Added a curly brace after if (infoContainer!=null) and another one after $("#updField").text(infoContainer.text());. Does not work. I do like the idea of firing the event from the parent, just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Updated with full code.  Sorry about the transcription/copy paste errors.

Comment: iFrame disappears after 3 seconds. During the time it is displaying, the date is displayed on the iFrame page and not in the parent div.

Comment: Can you take a look at it here?  http://mikesimon.com/stack/blah.html  It appears to be working in Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I just made minor changes in your code and that's working for me.
Here is my demo code : 
Main File : index.html
NOTE : Please update file path in Iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="updField" style="display: block; float: left; margin: 12px 0px 0px 20px; width: 300px; font-size: 14px; color: #CC0000;">Test Update Field</div>
<iframe src="http://localhost/other/stckoverflow/update-parent-content-from-iframe/file.php">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Iframe File : file.php

```
<?php
    $msg='no message text';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        if(isset($_POST['msg'])){ $msg = $_POST['msg'];}
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name='msg' />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#updField", window.parent.document).text("<?php echo $msg; ?>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```